# Custom xml packet in android

Tags: android, xml, client-server, packet

Can we create/construct a custom xml packet in android? I need to create an xml packet in the format shown below and send it to the server.

Sending a packet to the server can be done using the DatagramSocket and DatagramPacket according to the links similar to this [link](http://gwyneth.blogspot.in/2011/02/android-udp-client-code-snippets.html). But how do I accomplish the task of creating a custom xml packet? Couldn't find much help in google.

xml format:

```
 <a_list>
   <packet_count>12</packet_count>
     <info>
       <id>12345</id>
     </info>
 </a_list>
```

Comment: Check out this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6387947/how-to-send-custom-xml-packet-using-javas-smack-api) it may help you

Answer (score 0):

try out this-

```
String Data="<xml></xml>"           
Document docData= null;
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();          
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();          
InputSource is = new InputSource();
is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(Data));
docData = db.parse(is); 

        Element baseRoot=docData.getDocumentElement();  
Element root = docData.createElement("a_list"); 
baseRoot.appendChild(root); 

Element childpack = docData.createElement("packet_count"); 
root.appendChild(childpack); 

Text text = docData.createTextNode("12"); 
childpack.appendChild(text); 

Element childinfo = docData.createElement("info"); 
root.appendChild(childinfo );

Element childid = docData.createElement("id"); 
childinfo.appendChild(childid);

text = docData.createTextNode("12345"); 
childinfo.appendChild(text);
```