# add custom xml tags in XMPP Message Android

Tags: java, android, xml, xmpp, smack

I am sending xmpp message to my server and i want to add some custom xml tag to my message , i am sharing my required message format which i need to send to the server

```
<message id="8B3A2E64-827B-4F4C-9F52-C3BCFA0F801E" type="chat" to="spotauserdev439@ip-172-31-28-121.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal" from="spotauserdev437@ip-172-31-28-121.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal/30wvtftx7p">
    <channel>spota_1508227503</channel>
    <timestamp>1508768613141.54</timestamp>
    <subject>Spota Chat</subject>
    <body>Hg</body>
    <sendername>Swati</sendername>
    <senderid>437</senderid>
    <senderprofile>https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/spota/thumbnail/1508224847294238037.jpeg</senderprofile>
    <receiverid>439</receiverid>
    <height>0</height>
    <width>0</width>
    <request
        xmlns="urn:xmpp:receipts"/>
    </message>
```

i am using the below code to add custom xml tags in message but i am not able to create the correct format as above . i am using the below code and getting the below output , please anyone guide me

```
<message to='spotauserdev439@ip-172-31-28-121.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal' id='ae9800d1-1628-48ae-b462-2e8180adfab3' type='chat'>
    <body>sacas</body>
    <thread>d46b782c-a35e-49bd-b598-ecf053c976ca</thread>
    <height
        xmlns=''>
        <height>0</height>
    </height>
    <width
        xmlns=''>
        <width>0</width>
    </width>
</message>
```

and i am using this code :

```
final Message message = new Message();
            message.setType(Message.Type.chat);
            message.setBody(chatMessage);
            message.setStanzaId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());

            DefaultExtensionElement height = new DefaultExtensionElement("height","");
            height.setValue("height", "0");


            message.addExtension(height);
```

Comment: which smack version are you using?

Comment: org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.1.6

Comment: please check this ans it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26507753/how-to-add-custom-fields-in-message-elements-of-xmpp-stanza-packet/26509393#26509393

Comment: I have seen this but this didn't work for me, plz any other solution

Comment: if you add extensions you have to add namespace mandatory.
this is only way to create custom message like your requirement https://stackoverflow.com/a/8991344/7229971

Comment: org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message is Final class now , you can not extent it now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157430/discussion-between-kuldip-patel-and-achin).